# How to pass an array of jsons from script section of html file to javascript index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have an array of jsons created in a html file that I would like to pass to the server. When I print out the array in the console just before attempting to POST the results, everything shows up normal. Here is the contents of what I am trying to pass, which is contained in a variable called results:

```
0: {id: 02934, uName: "Ben", favFood: "ice cream"}
1: {id: 02474, uName: "Sam", favFood: "ice cream"}
2: {id: 01582, uName: "Jamie", favFood: "broccoli"}
```

But when I go into req.body I find that the array I am trying to pass has undefined variables:
[image]

I am attempting send the data through an jQuery call seen below:

```
$("#sendResults").click((event) => {
    console.log(results);
    $.ajax({
         url: '/entertimes',
         type: 'POST',
         data: results
    });                    
});
```

My goal is to pass the data to the server in a way that is easily manipulatable, meaning that **if I typed console.log(req.body.results[0]) it would print out the json contents at that point.**

---

Note: if I update the code to what I have below, i am able to get a string of the json array that I could potentially parse to get the information. However, I want to avoid having to parse it if there is an easier way:

```
$("#sendResults").click((event) => {
    console.log(results);
    $.ajax({
         url: '/entertimes',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {results: JSON.stringify(results)}
    });                    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transmite data from/to server and client side always is in json format. The json is a string. When you send the data, should use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() to use the json like an object.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Do you have any advice about how to parse the resulting string from JSON.stringify()? Because of the way the req.body.results object is formatted, I cannot just call JSON.parse(results).

Comment: seems like you do not format well the json object. This is the correct format `[{"foo": 1}, "bar": "some"]`